# Dart Utf8Decoder convert crashes with special characters

Tags: flutter, dart, stdout

I'm my Flutter project, I'm facing a weird problem. When I run the following:

```
var test = Utf8Decoder().convert("ô".codeUnits);
```

I get the following error:

```
Unfinished UTF-8 octet sequence (at offset 1)
```

It looks like the `ô` character is consided as a malformed character or something.

It's actually very annoying because I use the `Utf8Decoder` with the `Process` class to call an external app on Windows that returns information on the stdout as the following, and it crashes if that app returns something with a special character on the stdout:

```
_process = await Process.start("path/to/exe", ["args"]);
_process!.stdout.transform(utf8.decoder).listen(_onHandleStdout);

void _onHandleStdout(String out) { ... }
```

How can I fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: Strings in Dart are internally handled as UTF-16. So the values returned from `codeUnits` is UTF-16 and not UTF-8. So it makes sense you are getting an error. But I am not really sure what you are trying to do?

Comment: Note that when you spawn a new process, you can specify what charset stdout and stderr is encoded. So you need to make sure you are using the correct charset since you are otherwise going to get an error: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.0/dart-io/Process/run.html

Comment: @julemand101 Oh ok, interesting, that might be why it's not working, I'll try that out now.

Comment: On Windows, the `stdoutEncoding` is not defaulted to UTF-8. So if you are calling a program which will explicit return UTF-8 strings, you should specify it by setting `stdoutEncoding` with `stdoutEncoding: utf8` (remember to import `dart:convert`).

Comment: If you want to do your own decoding using `transform`, you should set `stdoutEncoding` to `null` based around the description in: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.0/dart-io/Process/run.html "The default encoding is systemEncoding. If null is used no decoding will happen and the ProcessResult will hold binary data."

Comment: That being said, I use the `Process.start()` method, and not the `Process.run()` method, as I need to listen to multiple events. But that method doesn't seem to allow me to specify the encoding...

Comment: Ah ok. With `Process.start` you will not have the automatically charset decoding and should not be a problem. If you are getting problems with `stdout.transform(utf8.decoder)` it could be that the process does actually not return UTF-8 encoded text. Are you in control over this program you are calling?

Comment: @julemand101 Yes I am, it's a Kotlin app. But again, if I do `_process!.stdout.listen((event) { print(event); }`, I get `[244, 13, 10]`. And 244 is 00F4 in hex, which is the Unicode value for the ô character... So I'm a bit lost to be honest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240011/discussion-between-julemand101-and-matteoh).

Answer (score 0):

After hours of research, here is the solution to my problem :

From the external app, I receive a list of UTF-16 characters on the stdout. But I tried to convert them using the UTF-8 decoder, which does not work when it comes to special characters (like `ô`).

So using `String.fromCharCodes()` as following works like a charm now:

```
_process!.stdout.transform(utf8.decoder).listen(_onHandleStdout);

void _onHandleStdout(String out) {
  print(String.fromCharCodes(out));
}
```